# Override f[k] += v for a class

Tags: python, python-3.2

I'm implementing a Fenwick tree class in python.

Basically I have an internal list and two methods, `get(key)` and `increase(key, inc)`, to handle reading and updating this list.
Mapping `f[5]` to `f.get(5)` is easy with `__getitem__`, but is there any way to make `f[5] += 2` mean `f.increase(5, 2)`?

I found a relevant [mailing list thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-August/1217533.html) that says it can't be done unless you wrap the results from `__getitem__` in a proxy-class that implements `__iadd__`, but that's not an option. So I'll probably have to accept that I'll have to use the `increase`-method, just thought I'd ask here just in case some genius has the solution.

I'm using python3.2 by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the approach you described is pretty much the only option. There may be minor variations, but there's no (sane, at least) way around the fact that `f[5] += 2` will call `__getitem__`, then `__setitem__`, and do the `+` part only on the object retrieved, without considering the container.

Comment: I'm not sure he's interested in the container for the `+=` part.

Comment: @jedwards: He wants `f[5] += 2` to be syntactic sugar for `f.increase(5, 2)`.

Comment: What I meant was if 5 and 2 are actually just integers, then this is easy enough (see my answer).  If they're objects, and the += operation somehow depends on their container `f` and not on the objects themselves, then it would be tricky but still do-able.

Comment: @jedwards Your answer assumes `increase` is `self._some_internal_collection[key] += value`. Considering that OP has a Fenwick Tree, I strongly doubt it's like that. Please read again, carefully, and should you come to the conclusion your answer *does* related to OP's case, then please enlighten me.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is just not true.  It doesn't assume that -- that is just a simple explanation of how it could be done.  In fact, any arbitrary mapping from k to a value would be possible, not just `container[k]`.  For example, `fh.seek(k*2); return fh.read(2)` would return the kth pair of bytes from a file.  The assumption I am making, however, is that he's working with integers for both the value of `f.get(k)` and `v` -- but as I said, that wouldn't be that hard to fix if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what `v` is and if you can edit the code defining the class `f`:

For the case where `v` is an integer, and you can edit the code of class `f, this is certainly possible:

```
class alist(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.L = list()

    def append(self, v):
        self.L.append(v)

    def increase(self, k, i):
        self.L[k] += i

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.L[k]

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.L[k] = v

a = alist()
a.append(8)
a.append(1)
a.append(15)
a.append(57)

print "List contains: ", a.L

print "This should be eight: ", a.get(0)

# Increase using the increase method
a.increase(0,2)

print "This should be ten: ", a.get(0)
print "This should be ten: ", a[0]

# Increment using the [] getitem shortcut
a[0] += 2 

print "This should be twelve: ", a.get(0)
print "This should be twelve: ", a[0]


print "List contains: ", a.L
```

Which displays:

```
List contains:  [8, 1, 15, 57]
This should be eight:  8
This should be ten:  10
This should be ten:  10
This should be twelve:  12
This should be twelve:  12
List contains:  [12, 1, 15, 57]
```

No need for wrapping in a proxy-class, no need to define `__iadd__` since it's already defined for integers.  Now, if you're working with some other element datatype (like a custom object), you may need to define `__iadd__`.

Comment: No, updating the internal list isn't that simple. `increase(key, inc)` does more than just increase the element at index `key` in the internal list by `inc`.

Comment: Btw, `__iadd__` is not defined for integers since integers are immutable but `__add__` will be used instead automatically.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missing something, but why can't you just call increase on `setitem`? e.g.

```
class FTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # could be any data structure, on which get and increase work
        self._data = [1,2,3,4] 

    def get(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

    def increase(self, key, value):
        print "increasing item",key,"by",value
        self._data[key] += value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.increase(key, value - self.get(key)


f = FTree()
f[2] += 2
print f[2]
```

output:

```
increasing item 2 by 2
5
```

isn't it what you want?

Comment: For one, `f[2] = 4` would call `increase()` -- and although it would result in the correct outcome, it would certainly be weird if a simple assignment called the "increase" function.

Comment: @jedwards I am assuming he has some complex code in `increase` and `increase` is the proper way of changing list, otherwise plain getitem and setitem will suffice

Comment: This could work (if `self._data[key]` was replaced by `self.get(key)` in `__setitem__`) but that would make increments using `+=` less efficient than using `increase` (since it would also have to do a `get`).

Comment: @Snago I would change it to get, and I don't think there is anyway otherway except to have such a wrapper